# why the result of "select '441000000000007999400540' = 441000000000007999671682" is 1 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I hava a mysql database with version of 5.7.28。

When I execute

```sql
select '441000000000007999400540' = 441000000000007999671682
```

the result is 1.

How it happen?

I gauss,it is about implicit type conversion.

According some results of google searchs,Mysql will convert varchar to integer when do varchar to number comparisons.Thus the execute result will be 0.

So what's the rules about what mysql will do in such situations?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html#:~:text=Some%20conversions%20occur%20implicitly.,as%20necessary%2C%20and%20vice%20versa.&text=It%20is%20also%20possible%20to,because%20it%20expects%20string%20arguments.

Comment: `CAST(... AS DOUBLE)` explains.. https://dbfiddle.uk/K9ZmSePl

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL documentation explains the [type-conversion rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) when expressions containing values of different types are evaluated:

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts strings to numbers as necessary, and vice versa.

It also says below:

> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations:
>
> - ... 
>   ...
> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (double-precision) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

Lower, on the same page it details the topic:

> Comparisons between floating-point numbers and large values of `INTEGER` type are approximate because the integer is converted to double-precision floating point before comparison, which is not capable of representing all 64-bit integers exactly. For example, the integer value `2`<sup>`53 + 1`</sup> is not representable as a float, and is rounded to `2`<sup>`53`</sup> or `2`<sup>`53 + 2`</sup> before a float comparison, depending on the platform.
>
> To illustrate, only the first of the following comparisons compares equal values, but both comparisons return `true`:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT '9223372036854775807' = 9223372036854775807;
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT '9223372036854775807' = 9223372036854775806;
>         -> 1
> ```

The biggest integer value that can be represented exactly using the floating-point number representation (with double precision) is `9007199254740991` (`2`<sup>`53`</sup>`-1`). Beyond this value, the integer values cannot be represented exactly and are rounded to the nearest value that can be represented exactly ([which is always a multiple of a power of `2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values).)

Between `2`<sup>`53`</sup> and `2`<sup>`54`</sup>`-1`, only the numbers that are multiple of 2 can be represented exactly. The odd numbers are rounded to the nearest even number (and the nearest even number is not always in the same direction). Between `2`<sup>`54`</sup> and `2`<sup>`55`</sup>`-1` only the multiples of 4 can be represented exactly, between `2`<sup>`55`</sup> and `2`<sup>`56`</sup>`-1` only the multiples of 8 can be represented exactly and so on, and so forth.

Your number uses 79 bits in its binary representation. At that magnitude, only one out of each 32 million numbers can be represented exactly using the floating point numbers representation. The others are rounded.

Use type [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) to store such large values exactly and handle them as numbers. The `DECIMAL` type is able to store integer numbers up to 65 decimal digits in length (yours are 24 digits, you are safe and there is a lot of room for expansion). Or store them as strings if you don't need to do arithmetic operations with them.

For comparison with literal values you need to use the [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function.

Read more about how MySQL handles the [precision math](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math.html).